# Excel 2007 macro buttons greyed out

Tags: excel, vba

My macro options are greyed out in Excel 2007. i've adjusted the settings in the trust center and attempted to install the VBA add-in.

I cant record or enable any macros. How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any addin loaded at startup? Does this happen with every file or a specific one? You need to tell us more if you want some help.

Comment: every file. nothing beyond the Analysis ToolPak is active on my add-ins

Answer (score 2):

figured it out - it had to do with the initial install. the option to install "with VBA components" was never selected. had to uninstall, then re-install.

now it works beautifully. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Jason,

The first thing to check is if you can run any macro's at all. What happens when you have the sheet with the macro buttons open and you then open the macro selector ([Alt]+[F8])?

If you can see and run the macro's from there, then you know that running the macro's is not blocked. In that case you could try to add a new set of buttons and throw the old (non-functioning) buttons away. Adding a button is easy. Make sure you have the "developer" tab available (enable in options) and select "controls", "insert". When you click on the button icon, a list of available macros should pop-up.

What I think has happened though is that the macro's where stored in PERSONAL.XLSB and that the sheet (with the buttons) does not contain the macro's. I.e. the sheet is an xlsx file and not an xlsm file. If the macro's where stored on an other sheet, you will have to copy the macro's to the sheet with the buttons. Use [Alt]+[F11] to open the macro editor and copy the macro's to the new sheet. In the macro editor, you will probably have to create a folder "Modules" by selecting "insert", "Modules".

If you need more help, just ask.

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Comment: Thanks Robert.  The macro selector feature does not load. No macros will open in Excel. Interesting fact - the macros selector window does populate in Word. 

I am positive the problem is not the fact that the macro is saved in a personal workbook.

Comment: Jason, just checking: in Macro settings, did you check the Trust access..... and selected anything BUT "Disable all macros without notification". Also in the add-ins section I have non of the options checked. (MS Office 2010 though). Regards,